# How to select Eloquent model without arguments

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I don't know if 'arguments' is the right term. I want to get a model without everything and add the `selects` and `wheres` later.

```
$query = Pic::;

if($cat) $query->where('cat',$cat);
if($year) $query->where('jahrprod',$year);

$query->get();
```

`Pic::` or `Pic` don't work. Only `DB::table('pics')` does, but does not seem to return a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Model::query();`

```
$query = Pic::query();

if($cat) $query->where('cat',$cat);
if($year) $query->where('jahrprod',$year);

$query->get();
```

Comment: I also tried `new Pic;` and it seemed to work, too. But I am not sure if it would cause problems. `Pic::query();` looks better